# How can I protect my php source files while opening other users

Tags: php

I have developed an web app in PHP, but without me my is client editing files using his knowledge. I want to stop him, to hide, protect or lock my php code. So, he has to come back to me for edits.

Comment: Does he have access to the server where the code is stored?

Comment: You want something like this: http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/

Comment: He is using godaddy server, opening files and editing tags and creating more sites him self, its not good, we are loosing billing.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software) personally I dont like, that kind of things is better in a contract

Answer (score 0):

If you put your code into Source Control, you can easily monitor and control what code changes are made to your application (and easily reverse them if needed). GIT is a very popular source control system, you should investigate it, this tutorial is very easy to follow: http://gitimmersion.com/

Comment: He's not looking for distributed SCM, he's looking for a recurring revenue stream.

Comment: Is there any possibility hide code or lock files, so that client will come back to me, other wise big application we build he is doing changes himself without maintenance, give me better solution to stop editing except me.